# Adding a class attribute on the Image tag generated by the hyperlink control

Tags: asp.net

I have a hyper link control and I set the NavigateURL and the ImageURL property at runtime. I also need to set the class of the image tag that it generates but I cannot figure out how I can do that. The solution mentioned here

[Apply CSS Class to Image in asp:Hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428879/apply-css-class-to-image-in-asphyperlink)

does not work because the image url is hard coded.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still be able to use that solution and just dynamically assign the image:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="linkclass" NavigateUrl="http://example.com">
   <asp:Image runat="server" Id="ImageLink" CssClass="imgClass" ImageUrl="paceholder.jpg" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Then in code behind you can easily set:

```
ImageLink.ImageUrl = "MyDynamicImage.jpg";
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if that work since it is inside a hyperlink control and I forgot to mention that all of this is in a GridView. It did work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to set the CssClass directly like this, but a workaround is to dynamically create an Image, and add it to the HyperLink's control collection, like so:

```
Image _img = new Image();
_img. ImageUrl = "image.jpg";
_img.CssClass = "myClass";
HyperLink1.Controls.Add(_img);
```