# How to access div tag and change style attribute in .NET?

Tags: c#, css, .net

We are using .NET. In code behind on page load we want to access the css style of div and put in some values.

We cannot add RUNAT="SERVER" to the div as it is on the master page. And this is another page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92427/apply-inline-css-to-an-asp-net-server-control or use a `.css` file. Your question could do with being a little more descriptive though, maybe include some code?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you would do it using the div but you could try using:

```
<asp:Panel Id="MyDiv" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Panel>
```

Asp:Panel gives you a div in the frontend. Then in the back-end you can use

```
MyDiv.CssClass = "MyDivClass";
```

This would render as

```
<div id="MyDiv" class="MyDivClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build up your CSS styles in a string and output to your page with an `<asp:Literal>` on page load, ideally in the `head` of your masterpage using a `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`.

On your page:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litCSS" runat="server" />
```

In your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string styles = "<style>div { color: black; }</style>";
    litCSS.Text = styles;
}
```

Comment: can you give any example / reference

Comment: @NachiketKamat I have edited my answer in an attempt to make it clearer, this is just a method of injecting CSS into your page from the code behind

Comment: But when does this get applied to the div. Does itwait for the page to load? otherwise there will be error right? I get "Unable to get property 'setAttribute' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: @NachiketKamat Yes, all it does is output the CSS to the page on load, so that is when the styles are applied to your element. The error you have is from somewhere else in your code, you should not need to call 'setAttribute'.

Comment: In my code the js script is var div = document.getElementById('suiteBarLeft');
   div.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #9C79C6;");

Comment: @NachiketKamat That is Javascript, your question is asking how to do this in the code behind which is what my answer relates to. If you want to do this in javascript and you are having problems I would suggest asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your problem can be fixed with :

```
 HtmlGenericControl control = Master.FindControl("snackbar") as HtmlGenericControl;
 control.Style.Add("background-color", "red")
```